# Why does scrollbar stop shrinking after screen goes below certain width?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm very new to HTML/CSS and I have what is probably a dumb question. I'm trying to create a row of four images that has a horizontal scrollbar created beneath it when the page width goes below the width of the four images (as well as some padding). I have most everything working as desired; however, my scrollbar stops shrinking once the page width gets below about 975 px (somewhere between images 3 and 4). I would expect the scrollbar to keep shrinking as I shrink the page width. Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

My HTML and CSS are below. I added a bit of background coloring to make it clearer where the images are (since I don't know how to upload images to SO that the HTML will be able to find). Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a dumb request.

```css
section {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      .subsection {
        width: 1160px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .image-container {
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 40px;
      }

      .image-box {
        flex: 0 0 260px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: rgb(163, 163, 241);
      }

      img {
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
      }
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="subsection">
        <div class="image-container">
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img1" alt="Image 1" />
          </div>
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img2" alt="Image 2" />
          </div>
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img3" alt="Image 3" />
          </div>
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img4" alt="Image 4" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: remove `overflow-x` from `image-container` class and put in `subsection` or `section` class, its depend on your requirements criteria.

Comment: Well, that was simple. Somehow, I thought I'd already tried that...thanks! If you post an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow-x` from `image-container` class and put it in `subsection` or `section` class, it depends on your requirements criteria.

```css
section {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      .subsection {
        width: 1160px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
      }

      .image-container {
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 40px;
      }

      .image-box {
        flex: 0 0 260px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: rgb(163, 163, 241);
      }

      img {
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
      }
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="subsection">
        <div class="image-container">
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img1" alt="Image 1" />
          </div>
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img2" alt="Image 2" />
          </div>
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img3" alt="Image 3" />
          </div>
          <div class="image-box">
            <img src="img4" alt="Image 4" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```